# ImageAssets not showing from flutter web build in github pages

Tags: flutter, github-pages, flutter-web

I built my portfolio site with flutter web and pushed to master. When i deploy it in my github pages, it is not showing on [here](https://sumitt1080.github.io/) my pic which i have added, but it is showing properly when i run it on local machine in chrome.
Here is my repo [my portfolio](https://github.com/sumitt1080/sumitt1080.github.io)
Any Clue what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The console is prompting 404 Error on assets/ravenclaw.png
Thats beacause your real file path is assets/assets/ravenclaw.png

If thats not fixing it, host your image elsewhere and use Image.network(). In my opinion that's easier for using Flutter Web.